# What's the best way to get top N elements in a Map<String, Double> based on their values?

Tags: java, functional-programming

For example, if I have a map consists of `{"A", 0.0}, {"B", 3.14}, {"C", 3.14}, {"D", 8.8}, {"E", 2.1}, {"F", 1.01}` and the top 3 keys would be `{"D", "B", "C"}`.

I know the procedural way to do this but is there a smarter/functional way to do it in Java 8?

Edit: note that we can put each element of the map into a priority queue of size N, so the time complexity should be M*log(N), faster than sorting all M elements which is M*log(M).

Edit 2: As requested, this is what I've got:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    final Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>() {{
      put("A", 0.0);
      put("B", 3.14);
      put("C", 3.14);
      put("D", 8.8);
      put("E", 2.1);
      put("F", 1.01);
    }};
    System.out.println("answer= " + getTopN(map, 3).toString());
  }

  static List<String> getTopN(final Map<String, Double> map, int n) {
    // Creating priority queue with limit size n
    PriorityQueue<Entry<String, Double>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(n, Entry.comparingByValue());
    for (Entry<String, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      pq.add(entry);
      if (pq.size() > n) {
        pq.poll();
      }
    }
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();
    while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
      stack.add(pq.poll().getKey());
    }
    final ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!stack.isEmpty() && n-- > 0) {
      answer.add(stack.pop());
    }
    return answer;
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values ... I think you just are looking for a Java 8 way to sort/iterate a map based on values.  Several of the answers in the above link show you how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values)

Comment: It's not duplicate. Because to sort the whole map sized M, time complexity is M log (M), whereas just to get top N, it's M log(N).

Comment: Priority queues in Java cannot be iterated. Best you can do is peek the min/max element in `O(1)` and pop/pull the min/max in `O(logN)`. Is this enough for your case?

Comment: It would also be useful if you could provide the imperative way you're doing this now (a simplified version, if possible)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I've edited my post to include what I had. Is it too ugly? I really can't think of a way to make it elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be improved by making use of [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#pollLast--) (instead of `PriorityQueue` and `Stack`):

```
static List<String> getTopN(Map<String, Double> map, int n) {

    TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Double>> topN = new TreeSet<>(
        Map.Entry.<String, Double>comparingByValue()
            .reversed()                         // by value descending, then by key
            .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey)); // to allow entries with repeated values

    map.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
      topN.add(e);
      if (topN.size() > n) topN.pollLast();
    });

    return topN.stream()
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note that I'm using a comparator that sorts the `TreeSet` of entries by value in descending order and then by key. This is to make it possible for the set to contain entries with equal values.

The [`TreeSet.pollLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#pollLast--) method is the equivalent of `PriorityQueue.poll()` method.

Comment: intellij IDE is saying the type of topN is 
TreeSet<Entry<Object, V>>

Comment: how do I hint the compiler? 
this is the error msg:
Error:(68, 54) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for java.util.TreeSet<>
    reason: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
      equality constraints: java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.lang.Double>
      upper bounds: java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.Object,V>,java.lang.Object

Comment: @ijklr Already fixed the compilation errors, see [ideone demo](https://ideone.com/mID8su)

Comment: yeah it works. I did some benchmark and it performs similarly to what I have. 
https://github.com/ijklr/stackoverflow

Comment: Maybe there's still room for some extra improvement (not sure if there will be some performance gain, though)... Instead of using a `TreeSet` for `topN`, you could use a `TreeMap<Map.Entry<String, Double>, String>`. Then, just return the values as a `Collection<String>`, or `new ArrayList<>(topN.values())` if you actually need a list.

Comment: @fps can this solution be extended to -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814841/how-to-find-top-n-with-priority-queue-and-conditional-based-approach

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way that uses a reverse Double comparator by entry value:

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", 0.0);
map.put("B", 3.14);
map.put("C", 3.14);
map.put("D", 8.8);
map.put("E", 2.1);
map.put("F", 1.01);

List<String> topKeys = map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.<Entry<String, Double>>comparingDouble(Entry::getValue)
                 .reversed())
        .limit(3) //limit to 3
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The returned list contains `[D, B, C]`

Comment: Looks nice! Can we do it functionally without sorting the whole map?like using a priority queue, Only need top N.

Comment: @ijklr You can replace that with a collection of pair objects... right?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by replacing, can you elaborate the question?

Comment: @ijklr instead of `map.entrySet().stream()`, use something like `Arrays.asList(Pair.of("A", 0.0), Pair.of("B", 3.14)...).stream()`. I'm referring to commons-lang's Pair class

Comment: I see. If we are sorting the whole  M elements, then sorting array is probably more efficient than sorting a map?. But I don't think sorting the whole thing is necessary to get top N.

Comment: After running your code, I think it does not return C as the answer, because it would have a duplicate key of 3.14, same as B's key.

Comment: You could change `Comparator.<Entry<String, Double>>comparingDouble(Entry::getValue).reversed()` by `Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed()` . See [`Map.Entry` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--)

Comment: @ijklr You can always do a partial sort instead of a full sort. For example by inserting all values into a `PriorityQueue` and then polling `N` elements out of it.

Comment: @ernest_k sorry, your code actually worked and I just interpreted the result wrong.(I was testing on a more complicated test case and confused myself..) I ran on my example and it worked.